# How to count number of E-mails sent from a single account in Postfix?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server

I am using Postfix mail server. How can I count number of E-mails sent from a single account in an hour?

Comment: it looks like you can do this with [anvil](http://www.postfix.org/anvil.8.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# now=`date '+%b %d %H:%M'`
# prev=`date '+%b %d %H:%M' -d  "1 hour ago"`
# sed -n "/$prev/,/$now/p" /var/log/mail.log | egrep 'from.*someuser' | wc -l
```

Comment: We can't rely on "from" since it can be spoofed.

Comment: You will need to mitigate spoofed mail at the MTA (spamassassin). Anything downstream (procmail, maildrop, etc) which could be of use is going to assume the envelope info is all legit.

Answer (score 2):

Give a look at [`pflogsumm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pflogsumm)

It can show a per-email-count sorted list of both sent and received email.